# Hide transparent dialog view when clicking on the screen

Tags: android

I have this transparent window created at on create, how can I make it that instead of having to press the back button, the view is hidden while pressing anywhere on the screen?

Code:

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.help);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                        
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
```

---

### Solution:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        rl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }   
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
dialog.setCancellable(true);
```

### EDIT:

@Val You can add click listener on the view of dialog and dismiss it

Comment: doesn't work. It still only gets canceled if I press the back button. I want it to disappear when pressing anywhere on the screen

Comment: Do you want on only background or on dialog too?

Comment: any. The dialog takes all of the screen, so anywhere would be fine

Comment: @Val You can add click listener on the view of dialog and dismiss it.